# Java - for() loop and arrays

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

The next question is from test that I've done.. I've run the code on BlueJ and don't get why the return value is 5...

```
public int mystery(int[] myStuff, int num) {

    for (int k = myStuff.length - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
        if (myStuff[k] < num) {
            return k;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

> `myStuff` = 2, 4, 0, 1, -6, 3, 8, 7, 5
>
> `num` = 4

In the test I wrote - 0. Why 5? I don't get it!

What is the part of the

```
`return -1`
```

?

Comment: Well, I don't get why you think the answer is 0 either.

Comment: The test was on paper, that was the last question.. i wrote that many times and that what i got...

Comment: myStuff[k] in the last run off the for loop  = k = 0. k[0] = 2. 2< 4... so return the k = 0. that was my mistake, but i dont see why. i know that it's mistake.. but why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting 5 because that is the *index* of the first element in the array whose value is less than 4 (when starting from the last element and working towards the first).  Note that you have:

```
return k;
```

...where `k` is your array index.  If you wanted to get the value at that index, you should do:

```
return myStuff[k];
```

Here's a simple example that shows that your result is in fact correct:  http://ideone.com/7byIY

And the `return -1;` is just saying "if no elements are less than the specified number then return a value of -1 to indicate that no match was found".  This is not an uncommon practice (returning an intentionally chosen, invalid value to indicate that there is no result).

Comment: So... couple guys here told "the largest value" and you say "the first element..." and i guess you'r right (they answer dont wrong i guess...but.. your explanaiton is the best for me.

Answer (score 2):

It returns five because that's the index of `3` in your input array, which is the first number strictly smaller than `4` starting from the end of your array.

`return -1;` would be executed if none of the items in your array satisfy the "strictly smaller than num" criteria.

Answer (score 1):

The function returns the largest index in the array corresponding to a value less than the target. This is accomplished on arbitrary arrays by scanning from the back and returning the first index corresponding to a value less than the target. In your example, 3 < 4 at index 5, so this is the correct answer. If no values smaller than the target are found, -1 is used as a sentinel value to indicate the algorithm failed to find a valid answer.

Answer (score 1):

That function gives the position of the last number in the first argument that's smaller than the second argument (or -1 if all the numbers are larger than the second argument; -1 is a special value with no chance of ambiguity because there's no position -1).

That number is 3 and its position is 5 (starting with 0).

Answer (score 1):

This function just searches for the last value in the array which is greater or equal than `num`. Let's compute the check `myStuff[k] < 4` for all values:

```
   0      1     2     3     4     5      6      7     8   // k
   2      4     0     1    -6     3      8      7     5   // myStuff[k]
true  false  true  true  true  true  false  false  false  // myStuff[k] < 4
```

The last index for which `myStuff[k] < 4` is true is obviously 5, so that's the correct answer.

`return -1` is needed so that the function returns a value, even if all elements of `myStuff` are larger than num. For example, with `num = -99`, the result would be -1.

Answer (score 0):

your return-1 doesn't mean anything for the parameters you have passed here. 
as the condition is true for value 3 so it returns the value of k, which is nothing but 5 bt that movement. this is because you are iterating backwards.

Answer (score 0):

mystery(myStuff=[2,4,0,1,-6,3,8,7,5], 4)

then the for begins

for (int k = 8; k>=0; k--) 
   if (  myStuff[8]=5  < 4)  - NO

2nd iteration

k = 7   if (7 < 4) - NO

... so on

k = 6   if (8 < 4) - NO

k = 5   if (3 < 4) - YES - so return k = 5

The last part means:
if myStuff does not have any value < num then it returns -1

Comment: When the if gets: k = 5 if (3 < 4) - YES - so return k = 5  - it's stopped and dont contenu to the next value? (k[4]=-6) ?

Comment: yes, because the return ends the method execution. http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=280